# Add a body class related to the product category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, categories

How can I add a body class related to the product category slug?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi , please read this article before posting : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  and read all of the articles stackoverflow provide to ask good question : http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wc_cat_names' );
function wc_cat_names( $classes ) {
    if(is_product()){
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $classes[] = $term->slug;
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

This one will work only in woocommerce product page and Yes I tested this on my test site.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty good guide for doing exactly this on the Wordpress support site: [Modify body_class() output to show category-{slug} for single posts](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/modify-body_class-output-to-show-category-slug-for-single-posts?replies=11#post-1396482)

I have altered the code from the post to suit your needs:

```
add_filter('body_class','add_category_to_single');
function add_category_to_single($classes, $class) {
    if (is_single() ) {
        global $post;
        foreach((get_the_category($post->ID)) as $category) {
            echo $category->cat_name . ' ';
            // add category slug to the $classes array
            $classes[] = $category->slug;
        }
    }
    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Honestly no, not at the time of answering. I used a modified version of it in an earlier project, which is why I remembered the post.

Comment: But according to [Wordpress Codex: body_class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) it should still be a valid hook.

Comment: this give me a php error and add the body_class to the another div. The error: `Warning: Missing argument 2 for add_category_to_single(`

Comment: Yes al right for this hook, is a classic hook, no problem… but woocommerce categories are a little different from wordpress ones… Don't worry, just asking :)

Comment: It was your Idea… but as I said untested. Too many `reputation` opportunism, sorry for you.